# Mongo aggregation $match equivalent of {$where: "this.field1 !== this.field2"}

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So I have this query,
`db.collection.find({$where: "this.field1 !== this.field2"})`

But now I need to create a similar query and aggregate the results in a complex query which tried and true, only can be done by using the aggregation pipeline or go "cannon for a fly" and use the mapReduce option.

Since I want to avoid mapReduce, is there a way to achieve something similar to the `{$where: "this.field1 !== this.field2"}` approach?

**Some observations**, an answer to the general approach to solve the situation above is most desirable, but in case that is not possible, in order to solve my problem, I can also use the raw value in the query with the following restrictions. I need to find what follows

```
db.collection.find({ $or :[
    {field1: value},
    {field2: value}
], $and: [
    { field1: {$not: {$eq: value}}},
    { field2: {$not: {$eq: value}} }
]})
```

I tried the above query but it discards results that contains the value in either field, and what I want is a way to discard the objects that have the same value **in both fields at the same time**, but obtain the documents that have the value in either field, I usually prefer an one query approach but after reading a lot, I think the only alternative to avoid mapReduce, is to do something like

```
db.collection.find({$where: "this.field1 === this.field2"}, function (err, results){
    var match = { $or :[
        {field1: value},
        {field2: value}
        ], { 
        _id : { $not : {$in: results.map((x) => x._id)}}
    }
    db.collection([ {$match: match}, {$project: projectionObject}, ...., etc])
})
```

So I'm going to use the be solution above, which can be optimized a lot, (I just wrote it while writing the question), but I would like to avoid sending an incredibly big list of objectIds back to the database if at all possible. I will refactor it a bit to use matching operators before the where statement

Comment: Yes, is a duplicate, and I really tried hard to find a solution back then. What do I do? Just Leave it be? Close? or merge the questions? I feel this one is more general, or I can edit it to be more general. Besides, this question is about how to transform the intuitive where('this.a $operator this.b'), and the other addresses the same problem, but it is stated exclusively in the context of $match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that's complex case, and maybe you could use a trick with `$cond` inside `$project`

```
var projectDataForMatch = {
    $project : {
        _id : 1, //list all fields needed here
        filterThisDoc : {
            $cond : {
                if  : {
                    $eq : ["$field1", "$filed2"]
                },
            then : 1,
            else  : 0
        } //or use compare operator $cmp
    }
}
}

var match = {
    $match : {
        filterThisDoc : 1
    }
}

db.col.aggregate([projectDataForMatch, match])
```

you can extend `$cond` to fit your needs as desired.

Comment: I like this approach, I'll wait the day to see if something easier to read comes up, or else I think I would accept this answer, also this gives a lot of flexibility not only to solve this scenario, but a lot of very complex queries can be written with this trick.

Comment: Since the pipeline allows to use match several times, I can filter a lot of resutls before, then apply this trick and match again to reduce the workload of the cond operation.

Comment: @galileopy - that's the power of aggregation :-)